# How does the initial 50% XP bonus work with the premium rocket pass?

Tags: rocket-league

How does the initial 50% XP bonus work with the premium rocket pass?

If I'm on tier 50 of the rocket pass can I expect to get an immediate tier up? How big will it be?

Answer (score 2):

Except for the 10k experience bonus from tier 55, upgrading to the Premium Rocket Pass does not give you any retroactive bonus XP.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, the XP boost affects XP gained via matches and **not** the XP gained via other sources (i.e. XP rewards from Rocket Pass tiers).

Comment: Isn’t there a initial 50% XP bonus as well though?

Comment: I used "XP boost" to define both the Premium Pass XP boost and XP boosts from special events.